# How to create publish script without write access to target (__RefactorLog)?

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I get an error message when trying to genereate publish scripts for our production database, using msbuild. There is only read access available to the production dbserver (public, Connect SQL, View any definition, and View server state are granted).

The SELECT permission was denied on the object '__RefactorLog'

Please, how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Have you tried making sure whatever login you're using definitely has select permission granted for that table? Does the table even exist in that database?

Comment: The table does not exist and the login doesnt have permission to create it. I guess there is no other way than to create the table and grant permission to it.. not good since it is a production server..

Comment: Except if you're using SSDT to publish your changes you'll be creating this table at some point anyway. This is the table used to handle all renames and refactor operations within SSDT. I understand the reluctance to make this change but unless you want to come up with a completely separate way to make these changes, you'll run into this problem eventually.  Now if the change was made and reverted, you can clear them out of the refactor.log file, but I would modify that carefully.

Answer (score 0):

May be this previous thread can help you:

[Error genereating publish script: the select permission was denied on the object __refactorlog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426103/error-genereating-publish-script-the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object)

Just my 2 cents

Comment: That was me double-posting.. Sorry for that!